# Given non-orthonormal set $\{f_n\}$, there are no scalars s.t.: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n f_n = (1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},\dots)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Given: $$f_1=(1,0,0,\dots), f_2=(1,1,0,0\dots),
> f_3=(0,1,1,0,0\dots), \dots \subseteq l^2(\mathbb{N})$$ prove that there are no scalars such that:
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n f_n =
> (1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},\dots)$$

This is part of a multipart question where I have already shown that:

1. $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is an independent set
2. $\overline{span\{f_i\}_{i=1}^\infty}=l^2(\mathbb{N})$

(the goal is to show that if the requirement that the system is orthonormal is dropped then even if the set's span is dense in a Hilbert space it will not necessarily be a basis).

I tried proving by contradiction using the following approaches:

- Writing out the resulting system of equations of the coefficients to find a pattern that could help me refute an earlier claim (e.g. $\alpha_1+\alpha_2 =1$ etc.)
- Trying to come up with a non-trivial linear combination that equals $0$ to show it contradicts the fact that it's an independent set.
- Thought of showing they must be orthogonal for some reason, but this was more of an intuition (wasn't able to come up with anything practical).

None of these were fruitful. What am I missing?

Comment: If the series converges, then $\alpha_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Try solving the infinite system of $\alpha_n$s and the divergence of $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$.

Comment: @TheoBendit I did try something of the sort, where I reached the conclusion that for all $N$ $\alpha_1+\alpha_N=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{N-1}$, but then got confused with taking this to $\infty$. Also - how can I formally claim that $a_n \to 0$?

Comment: @Anon For $n>1$, $|\alpha_m|\sqrt2=\Vert \sum_{n=1}^{m}\alpha_n f_n-\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \alpha_n f_n\Vert\rightarrow0$ (if the sum converges).

Comment: Make that "for $m>1$" above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is the way to go.

You can quite easily show that if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n f_n = \left(1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},\dots\right),$$

then

$$\begin{align}
\alpha_2 &= 1 - \alpha_1\\
\alpha_3 &= \left(1 + \frac12\right) + \alpha_1\\
\alpha_4 &= \left(1+\frac12 +\frac13\right) - \alpha_1\\
\vdots\\
\alpha_n &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i} + (-1)^{n+1}\alpha_1\\
\vdots
\end{align}$$

from this, you can conclude that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_n f_n$$ does not converge in one of two ways.

One, you can remember that if the series converged, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n$ would be equal to $0$. Since that limit is not $0$ (regardless of what $\alpha_1$ is equal to!), the series does not converge, so you have a contradiction.

Or, alternatively, you can directly look at the value of

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha_n f_n - \left(1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},\dots\right)$$

and notice that the norm of this value is **not** dropping to zero.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just struggling with proving two details in your proof: (1) that the limit is not $0$ regardless of what $\alpha_1$ is - how do I show this?  Tried using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition but not sure which $\epsilon$ fits and (2) That the norm is not dropping to $0$

Comment: @Anon $\alpha_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac1i$, plus or minus some constant. The limit of $\alpha_n$ is $\infty$ because the harmonic sum diverges.